# Does RcppArmadillo have yet an arma::Cube type for character arrays?

Tags: rcpp

I am slowly getting into Rcpp, mainly because I'm finding my own R simulation algorithm to be extremely slow-going. I am looking for small examples and then trying to scale up, even though I first naively tackled a complex Rcpp routine head-on.

In integrating R with C++, I know that RcppArmadillo arma::Cube has many types including int, float and double, but what I am really looking for though is a type for characters similar to as.character() in R. I have not been able to find any small, simple scripts illustrating this.

I have used the below resource for guidance

http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Cube

as well as guides by Dirk Eddelbuettel and Hadley Wickham.

Does anything like this exist yet for RcppArmadillo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and that is clearly stated right at the site you link to:

[image]

Apologies for the image, but the formatting does not cope well with copy and paste.  The money line is

```
The cube class is Cube<type>, where type is one of:
    float, double, std::complex<float>, std::complex<double>, 
    short, int, long and unsigned versions of short, int, long
```

All numbers. Nothing else.

Comment: Thanks Dirk. Are there plans in the future for such an implementation I will eventually be need of?

Comment: You need to talk to Conrad about his plans, I cannot speak for him.